# How to set the infopath dialog window default size to maxmize.?

Tags: infopath

I have a list InfoPath form, when I click on "add new item" the InfoPath form opens in a very small window.

I want to set InfoPath form dialog window to maximize size.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to over-ride the base functionality of the 'add new item' link using javascript or jquery upon page load, OR create a link on a page that utilized the following method:
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. bit i want to know any setting we can do using OOB only.

Comment: I have tried that option as well. It increase scroll bar only. Thanks, gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Customise the form using infopath designer and increase the table height and width which is conatining the contents. It might help you.

Comment: This answer needs more information. How can this be done?